# I have a function that is still affecting the position of a div when a media query is called, I want to stop it

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using a function that makes an element fixed on scroll, I don't want this function to still be in affect when I trigger a media query.

```
function scroll_fixbar() {
    var topBar = $("#latestWrapper");
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 145) {
        if (topBar.css('position') !== 'fixed') {
            topBar.css("position", "fixed");
            topBar.css("top", "0px");
        }
    } else {
        if ($("#AddFixedLatest").css('position') !== 'static') {
            topBar.css("position", "absolute");
            topBar.css("top", "145px");
        }
    }
}

function media_query(obj) {
    size = obj();
    var pathname = window.location.href;
    if (size != currentSize) {
        var sideBar = $('#sidebarWrapper');
        var wrapper = $('#wrapper');
        var menuBtn = $('.menuButton', '#menuOption');
        if (size == 'mobile') {
            currentSize = 'mobile';
        }
        if (size == 'tablet') {
            currentSize = 'tablet';
        }
        if (size == 'laptop') {
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                scroll_fixbar();
            });
            currentSize = 'laptop';
        }
    }

};

$(window).resize(_.debounce(function () {
    media_query(mqCSS);
}, 10));


$(window).load(function () {
    media_query(mqCSS);
});
```

When resizing the browser the `scroll_fixbar();` css attributes are still affecting my div when I trigger the "tablet" media query.

What can I do to stop this from happening, is their a way to "refresh" the div, or switch the function off when `(size == 'tablet')`

Help appreciated.

Comment: How are you calling `media_query()`?

Comment: Where is mqCSS defined, and what value is assigned to it?

Comment: Erm, scroll down? I'm using `$(window).resize()` to call `media_query()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    if (size == 'mobile') {
        currentSize = 'mobile';
        $(window).off('scroll', scroll_fixbar);
    } else if (size == 'tablet') {
        currentSize = 'tablet';
        $(window).off('scroll', scroll_fixbar);
    } else if (size == 'laptop') {
        $(window).on('scroll', scroll_fixbar);
        currentSize = 'laptop';
    }
```

Comment: Ah, that's it, I tried `$(window).off(scroll_fixbar);` but it didn't work, so did I have to include the scroll event?

Comment: The first argument to `off` is always the event whose handler is being removed. The function is optional, the event is not.

Comment: Also, make sure you use a named function when adding the handler. You can't remove an anonymous function by name.